# In association rule mining, is it okay to disregard single item purchases?

Tags: association-rules

I'm doing a market basket analysis of items purchases in particular stores. Each dataset contains over 5 million transactions. I'm currently processing this in R, but it seems my computer can't handle such a large data file.

I notice that there are a lot of single-item purchases. Is it valid to disregard single item purchases and focus only on baskets containing 2 or more items?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't discard transactions, if you want to calculate any measures to evaluate how strong or good rules are.

E.g. let your items be A, B, C and the transactions (baskets)

A
A,B
A,B
C

You can calculate absolute frequency fr(A,B)=2 without caring about single A and single C. However, you can't evaluate the strength of rule A->B. 
If you include also single A you'll get fr(A)=3 correctly. Now you can calculate precision ('confidence') of A->B, P(B|A)=2/3. However, you will also need C to get the data size (n) correctly, here n=4. Now you can get the relative frequencies P(A,B)=2/4=0.5, P(A)=0.75, P(B)=0.5. Leverage of A->B is P(A,B)-P(A)P(B)=0.5-0.75*0.5=0.125.

Note: The problem is computationally demanding, if you want to find optimal rules without excessive minimum frequency thresholds. I would recommend and efficient C or Java implementation.